# How to print a value in ListView in Android?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, adapter

I am new to Android development. I am using `ArrayList` to store country names, then to display the country name in `ListView`, but the value are assign wrong, below attached the picture for your reference. How to display a order like Afghanistan (1st cell), Aland Island (2nd cell) etc...

Thanks

I tried the below code:

```
      private  ArrayList<String> Countryname = new ArrayList<String>(); 
      String dataAll;

      lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
      for(int i=0;i<allTitles.getLength();i++) {
            dataAll+=allTitles.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()+"\n";
            this.Countryname.add(dataAll);
       }

     lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(SampleAndroidActivity.
     this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Countryname));
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of copying try understanding the java code so you don't have these issues. Its a simple error with your String assignment. Learn your basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
     String dataAll="";

     lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
     for(int i=0;i<allTitles.getLength();i++)
     {
         dataAll=allTitles.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()+"\n";
         this.Countryname.add(dataAll);
     }
```

Because you are appending new values in dataAll so remove **"+"** sign from front.

```
dataAll=allTitles.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()+"\n";
```

Comment: Hi imran, i have one doubt in PayPal integration in Android, Can u please chat with me?

Comment: Thanks Imran, i will chat Evening at 7:00 PM?